# HTML DOM Parser can't get JavaScript countdown

Tags: php, javascript, html-parsing, countdown, simple-html-dom

I'm using HTML DOM Parser from http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

then I have problem that can't get text from countdown JavaScript in source link.

code from source: (this is Countdown JavaScript)

```
<div class="timeSection" align="right" style="width:285px;margin:132px 0 0 -50px;position:absolute;">
<div style="width:285px; height:58px;"></div>

<div id="countdown_575" style="padding-left:50px;" class="hasCountdown"><table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" width="230" style="" border="0"><tbody><tr><td width="75" align="center">111</td><td width="40" align="center">50</td><td width="70" align="center">49</td></tr></tbody></table></div> 
<script type="text/javascript">                         
                                jQuery('#countdown_575').countdown({until: +402717 , compact: true,timeSeparator: '',expiryText:'Expired',format:'HMS',expiryUrl:'http://www.ensogo.com.ph/manila/',layout:'<table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="0" width="230" style="" border = "0">' +
                                    '<tr><td width="75" align="center">{hnn}</td><td width="40" align="center">{mnn}</td><td width="70" align="center">{snn}</td></tr></table>'});                              
</script>                           
</div>
```

my code:

```
foreach($ColumnHTML->find('.timeSection') as $getTime)
{
    $Temp_Time = $getTime->innertext;

    $TimeCode = str_get_html($Temp_Time);

    foreach($TimeCode->find('td[width=75]') as $getHour)
    {
        $Hour = $getHour->plaintext;
    }

    foreach($TimeCode->find('td[width=40]') as $getMinute)
    {
        $Minute = $getMinute->plaintext;
    }

    foreach($TimeCode->find('td[width=70]') as $getSecond)
    {
        $Second = $getSecond->plaintext;
    }

    echo $Hour.":".$Minute.":".$Second . "<br/>";
}
```

then Output: (blank with colon)

```
::
```

Answer (score 0):

That will not work, since those values are dynamically inserted into the DOM on the client side via JavaScript. If you want to capture those values on the server, you can submit them using a form.

Answer (score 0):

When you parse html through php the javascript is not executed thats why you dont get a result. That you are trying to do its not possible. A simple way to do it is to use ajax in your javascript to store your counter (maybe in a session or in a database table).